# Grammar , conjunction, until, don't, shouldn't be used

Tags: grammar

1) I will not carry my phone to the bathroom. 
                              Or
2) I do not Cary my phone to bathroom.. 
Which of the above is correct? If statement one is wrong,  why it is grammatically not correct.. 
Please explain...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but this is what I think: The first sentence means you are not willing to carry your phone to the bathroom, you refuse. The second one means you are not in the habit of carrying your phone to the bathroom, you leave it outside when you go to the bathroom.